# Outlook Plugin - Searching Global Address book

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

Does anyone know how to search the Global Address Book on the exchange server? It seems the 'Address Book' is different to a public contact list, hence this popular example code (or similar) points to a completely different set of contacts:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook._NameSpace olNS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook._Folders oFolders = olNS.Folders;
Outlook.MAPIFolder oContactsFolder = olNS.Folders["Public Folders"].Folders["All Public Folders"].Folders["Contacts"];
```

I need to search for a specific contact name. PS:- I'm using outlook 2007.
Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you are online a call using [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa772170.aspx) would be the way to go, offline you are in looking at extended mapi there is an answer to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301135/programatically-accessing-offline-address-book-using-redemption) on SO using redemption.

Answer (score 0):

The process is very tedious and error prone.
I think you may find the bellow article at Add-In Express useful:

[HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/.)

I think it doesn't need their tools in order to work but I am not quite sure as I had them when I tried it.
The code is in VB but they have a sample project available for download in C# if you prefer. It is rather long and has lots of COM object calls, so experience with that will be necessary. Also I am not quite sure if it will work on the 64 bit version of Outlook. Maybe you want to try this first.